# MongoDB Subdocument Query Performance on Large Dataset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have created a schema for Conversations in MongoDB where Messages are stored as an Array of Objects in Conversations Object.

```
Conversation {
     company_id: { type:ObjectId, index: true },
     messages: [{
                  _id: { type: ObjectId, index: true }
     }]
}
```

There is a query I have in place that looks up a Conversation based on the company_id and _id of the first message sent in the array (that is being sent from another part of the application).

```
Conversation.findOne({ company_id: c_id, messages._id: firstMessage })
```

Theoretically, if a company has 100 million conversations, and each of those conversations has 1 million messages, how much of a performance issue will I have for the query of the subdocument, rather then me storing the first message id in the main Document and querying just the base object?

```
Conversation {
     company_id: { type:ObjectId, index: true },
     firstMessage_id: { type:ObjectId, index: true },
     messages: [{
                  _id: { type: ObjectId, index: true }
     }]
}

Conversation.findOne({ company_id: c_id, firstMessage_id: firstMessage })
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If your individual messages are 1 million, I would keep them in a separate collection altogether and use the aggregation framework's $lookup in version 3.4 to give you the outcome. Of course I would assume that the proper indices are in place in both collections and proper filters are used to MATCH the company.

Comment: Mario, thank you for the answer. In actuality I have messages as a separate collection with the ids stored in conversation, however I was more wondering about the query computation of an object find vs an subobject find.